# Stop Toggle when clicking on the link

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to implement a particular piece on a website that toggles down when I click on a link, if a toggle is already on the page then it will close this and open this selected one.

Please refer to here: http://jsfiddle.net/r79Nu/3/

The problem is I want it so when you click on a particular link, it will stop toggling down all together and remove it. At the moment, it will display a div whenever you click on the link for a second time.

Here is the code:

```
    $('#nav a').click(function () {
    var headerItem = $(this).attr('data-header');
    if ($('#header_container').is(':visible')) {
        $('#header_container').slideUp(500, function() {
            $('.header_item').hide();
            $('#'+headerItem).show();
            $('#header_container').slideToggle(500);
        });
    }
    else {
        $('#'+headerItem).show();
        $('#header_container').slideToggle(500);
    }

});
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: So you want it so if the link was already clicked the first time (and the expand happens), you don't want any extra clicks to reclose and reexpand the item that was already opened?

Like clicking `click_0` once, let it expand.  Then click `click_0` again, you want nothing to happen?  If you click the `click_01` you want it to behave as is now (close,reopen), yes?

Comment: @Walls I want to be able to click it, it expands and when you click on the link again, it stops expanding .. Hope this makes sense Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/r79Nu/1/ BUT with the functionality above

Comment: so you want it to like stop mid toggle?  In your fiddle example, when `click_0` then click it again real fast, stop the sliding down functionality?  So instead of displaying the entire block of text, you want to like stop and have it hiding the rest of that text (whatever wasn't shown when the 2nd click stopped the slide)?

So you would only have like 1-2 lines displayed instead of the full 4 in your example?

Comment: @Walls Sorry. Like with this:  jsfiddle.net/r79Nu/1 You click "click_0" and then it toggles down, it displays the content.. If you click again, what it will do is stop toggling, it won't show it again until you click on the link again and it'll toggle it.. Make sense?

Comment: So you want like a slow reveal?  I'm still confused on the functionality you want.  Sounds like you want stuff done in the grouping of 3 clicks, yes?

Click 1: Start toggling the display down.
Click 2: Stop the toggling at its current point? or ???
Click 3: Roll it back up?

Comment: @Walls No, not slow. I just want it so when you click on a "link" it shows the toggle (the slider comes down).. When you click again it again the (the slider goes up and stays up) .. Does this make sense? It doesn't have to be a slow reveal, just stops when I press the link again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a shot at what I think you want.  Again it is VERY unclear what the desired functionality is.  This will work with the first click expanding the correct text (header 1 or 2), and then on the second click to that initial click spot, it retracts the cover.  This hides that shown data, so when you click `1` you get `1`'s data, and vice verse with `2`.  Is this the correct functionality?

http://jsfiddle.net/r79Nu/23/

Comment: If that isn't what is desired, there was a small tweak I made to handle the text displaying in weird situations for the wrong item.  http://jsfiddle.net/r79Nu/27/ is a new revision.  Let me know if this is correct or if something is missing from the functionality. *fingers crossed*

Comment: @user1326876 did that work?!  Looks like it did, hope it was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code, so that it does not toggle if already selected.

```
$('#nav a').click(function () {
    var headerItem = $(this).attr('data-header');
    if ($('#header_container #'+headerItem).is(':visible')) {
        $('#header_container').slideUp(500);  // or whatever method to make it disappear
        return false;
    } 
    .... rest of your code ...
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. But sadly not. Please see: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/r79Nu/12/)[/link]

Comment: if u click it again again and again, it stays up. I thought that's what u wanted. Do u want to handle rapid click?

Comment: I want it to close the toggle.. So when you click it again, the "blue" hides away until you click on it again where it comes down..

Comment: Then, how about hiding it if already shown up, like modified code?